# Connect two devices with websockets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, websocket-sharp

I am new to websockets, please excuse me if the answer to my question is too obvious.

I'm using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp), as my goal is to build a Unity3D client  that connects to a server. (Actually I want to build it for webGL platform, so the client will be written in javascript). For now, both client and server are written in C#.

When compiled on localhost it works perfectly, also with multiple clients and also over a secure connection using a self-signed certificate. It also works fine if the client connects to an echo server (ws://echo.websocket.org).

So I moved forward and I tried to connect two of my computers. The idea was to run the server on linux and execute the client on a mac, so I substituted "localhost" for the linux IP on both client and server codes. When I execute it, Unity (client) keeps saying me "Not a local IP address" and it doesn't connect.

I thought this could be a firewall issue, and that first I should open the port used... Is that the case? If so, how can I open a concrete port on mac and on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. It was an issue with the server code, I don't know where was the error. Instead of using my c# server I used Node.js, and it works fine. I can connect from other computers without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bindings.

WebSocketServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);

Test if you can make a connection to ip:port.

iptables -L for listing the configured rules in Linux.

Comment: I was using WebSocketServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("linux local ip"), port);   

If I use IPAddress.Any, unity says "error CS0122: `System.Net.IPAddress.Any' is inaccessible due to its protection level"